# Can someone explain how they are splitting the image here?

Tags: python, numpy, vision

I don't understand how what each value represents, would someone be able to explain?

`img_left[:,0:150,:] = np.clip(img_left[:,:150,:]*1.5,0, 255)`

Comment: I am not sure about np.clip, as I have not yet used it but, in general I would say that img_left is a ndarray, the way it's split  suggest that it is sliced along the second index, taking the first 150 values.

What I mean is that by array[:. a:b, :] it is intended a 3d array vector that is taken by considering only the  positions between a and b in the second index, and including all the other indices

Answer (score 1):

It takes the first 150 columns of image (first dimension in image being rows, second being columns, and third usually RGB). when you call a dimension by `:` you are selecting all elements along that axis. And calling a dimension by `i:j` select all the elements between `i`-th and `j`-th (including i and excluding j) along that dimension. It then multiplies all those selected values to `1.5` and clips the values to be between 0 and 255.

Comment: "and clip the values*1.5 to be between 0 and 255." ;)

Comment: @Guimoute would it not be the same?

Comment: I don't think so. Take a grey image. (Values x 1.5) contained in [0, 255] makes a new image but brighter. (Values) contained in [0, 255/1.5] makes something with a weird threshold.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is using open-cv, but either way the numpy array is being indexed by `[:,0:150:,:]`, where : means to take all values when by itself, and `x:y` is all values from x to y. So that'd mean that all of the y values (open-cv works with y first, then x), the x values from 0 to 149, and all 3 color channels.